# How can I see a page's referrer in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, http-referrer

I've read the "answers" on [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/220155/view-page-info-in-chrome), which is pretty much what I'm asking, but no one actually provides an answer. Nowhere in the Developer Tools (that I can see, anyway) is there a clear indicator of the current page's referring page. This is something that's really easy to find in Firefox; just right-click and choose Page Info.

Where is this functionality in Chrome? If it's in the developer tools, which tab is it under? If it's not, is there an extension I can use to get this info? I've tried the Web Developer extension, and can't seem to find this very basic piece of info there, either.

EDIT TO ADD SCREENSHOT:

This is what I see when I open Developer Tools in version 8.0.552.224 (newest available for Linux.)
[image]

Per comments below (in case they get buried) this is what I've discovered about Chrome's built-in "referrer-finding":

- I need to go to Resources, then choose the individual page or file, then choose Headers
- It doesn't appear to work correctly for pages that were opened by right-clicking a link and choosing Open in New Tab (or Window.) I just opened the question that I linked to in my original post that way, and when I look at the referrer provided in the header link, it shows its own URL as the referrer, rather than this page's URL.

Can anyone explain why that would be? (I tried the same thing in Firefox and it showed the correct URL as the referrer.)

Comment: Perhaps you need to add what version of Chrome this is for @EmmyS

Answer (score 19):

Paste this code into the address bar:

```
javascript:alert(document.referrer)
```

or

open Developer Tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) and type `document.referrer` in the console.

Comment: The F12 / document.referrer is the easiest approach.  It appears that when you paste in a url that starts with "javascript:" into the address bar, chrome trims that part off, probably for security reasons.  So you have to type that back in.  This is in chrome 42.

Comment: The "referer" vs "referrer" thing is pretty comical.

Answer (score 16):

1. In the Developer Tools, go to the Network view (if it wasn't open when you loaded the page, you'll need to reload to get it populated).
2. Click on the main page request -- it should be at the top of the list.
3. When you click, the right pane will probably show the HTML for it.
4. Click on the "Headers" tab on the right side.

The Referer is shown in the list of Request Headers.

Comment: In your version @EmmyS, if you do not see 'Network View', it will be called 'Resources'

Comment: My version (9.0.597.45 beta) has both 'Resources' *and* 'Network'

Comment: I'm on 8.0.552.224 (the newest version available for Linux.) I've posted a screenshot up in my original post of what I see when I open developer tools' resources tab (there is no network tab.) Where exactly is the page request I'm supposed to click on?

Comment: OK, I did eventually find it, but damn is it buried. Isn't there some extension that would provide the info the way Firefox does, so that I can just right-click on the page and see the referrer?

Comment: Also, it doesn't appear to work correctly for pages that were opened by right-clicking a link and choosing Open in New Tab (or Window.) I just opened the question that I linked to in my original post that way, and when I look at the referrer provided in the header link, it shows its own URL as the referrer, rather than this page's URL.

Comment: this was a really helpful answer. I think my API request may not be working because my referrer policy is the default `no-referrer-when-downgrade` (although both source and destination are `https` in my application). See documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy

Comment: "Click on the main page request -- it should be at the top of the list." For me, it only seems to show page requests from after I opened Developer Tools. Meaning I must have already had Developer Tools open when the page was opened for this to work. Pages in new tabs don't open with Developer Tools open...

Answer (score 1):

There was [a bug in Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1935) where the browser would not send the Referer header if you right-clicked a link and selected "Open link in new tab".

This was fixed in Chrome 13.

Answer (score 1):

Right click -> Inspect element -> Console -> write "document.referrer"

This property will be unset some times when the traffic is direct.